# Let's make pressing uparrow on questions more fashionable

Tags: discussion, downvotes, upvotes

There are many questions on Stack Overflow that have 0 votes. This makes browsing questions more difficult because you can't easily filter in those quite interesting.

When you review questions, after pressing *Looks ok!* you are often asked to up arrow questions that are ok. I believe it should appear more often and not only in review mode as our forum should be more interactive.

It's very easy to get minused - great! Our community filters out SPAM and low quality questions.

Why can't we upvote those correctly asked questions. Our aim should be to aim - let's say - 2-5 upvotes for ok questions so they won't mess up with those great questions, but they won't also mess with those questions that are lucky not to get minused and are 0.

Comment: If anything, this site needs more downvotes. I already see lots of tat getting upvotes when it shouldn't. But alas.

Comment: Sure! All you have to do is make more good questions be posted. Simple, right?

Comment: *Why can't we upvote those correctly asked questions.* But you can. I'm confused about what you're actually asking to happen. Are you asking for there to always be a banner suggesting you up  vote?

Answer (score 12):

Right, I'll bite:

> There are many questions on StackOverflow that have 0 votes.

That means that they're not good enough or haven't gotten enough attention to be positively scored. Daily votes are limited. Users who are very active on SO often have to pick and choose what to vote on on any given day. Often times questions are "Meh" or "Bad but still meh" enough to not merit spending one of your downvotes, but certainly no upvote candidates either.

> When you review questions, after pressing Looks ok! you are often
> asked to up arrow questions that are ok.

Only if the triage review passes with 3x "Looks OK", meaning that not only you, but also 2 others thought it was OK. And even then its not really a call to upvote the post, just a call to check wether or not it deserves it (sometimes, posts are not closeable [so, worthy of "Looks OK"] but very much downvoteable.)

> I believe it should appear more often and not only in review mode as
> our forum should be more interactive.

No. First of all Stack Overflow is not a forum. We're a content focused Q/A site. The purpose of the whole voting system is to let users quickly distinguish decent posts from less decent posts. We don't need more badgering to upvote stuff. In the review queue, you kind of sign up for that (The whole purpose of the queue is to judge the content of posts), but if you're just browsing, sometimes you don't want to vote, sometimes you're just looking for a solution.

> It's very easy to get minused - great! Our community filters out SPAM
> and Low quality questions.

Actually, you're not supposed to downvote spam. You can flag it as spam and 6 such flags or one moderator validating such a flag will immediately destroy the post, and impose a -100 penalty on the poster. Spam isn't a matter for downvotes, its a matter for immediate deletion. Spam flags do carry a implicit downvote, though.

> Why can't we upvote those correctly asked questions.

We're already doing that. If anything, the balance is currently skewed in favor of too much stuff being upvoted, and not enough stuff being downvoted.

> Our aim should be to aim - let's say - 2-5 upvotes for ok questions so they won't mess up with those great questions

Our aim is for the users to make that call. If you feel like something deserves an upvote - upvote it. But in principle nobody is forced to vote and everybody is free to vote as they please (unless they're specifically targeting another user)

**In conclusion:**

I don't believe we need more upvotes, or a way of pushing users to upvote things more. Upvote what you feel deserves it and that is that.

Comment: "Only if the triage review passes with 3x "Looks OK", meaning that not only you, but also 2 others thought it was OK.": And even then it's only a slight suggestion, the post might still not merit it, or might even merit downvoting...

Comment: Also, you might want to add in your last point a bit about voting for the post,not for the score. You shouldn't "aim"for a post to get a certain score. It deserves an upvote? You upvote. Period.